# spatial non-stationarity, spatial durbin model "in differences" and bounds testing

Tags: spatial, cointegration, ardl

I have two spatially correlated series. Basic tests indicate spatial non-stationarity of both, but no cointegration ([Lauridsen & Kosfeld, 2006](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1435-5957.2006.00087.x/abstract)).

Does anything speak against differencing all variables once spatially (including the lags), and then applying bounds testing to the "unrestricted" error correction specification in analogy to time series ([Pesaran et al., 2001](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.616/abstract))?

And would impact calculation ([LeSage & Pace 2009, pp. 275-304](https://www.crcpress.com/Introduction-to-Spatial-Econometrics/LeSage-Pace/p/book/9781420064247)) still be necessary in such "in-difference" regression?